# The use of " to farm out something"

Tags: phrases

I would like to ask if I can use "[to farm out something](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/farm-out-something)" as in the following way.

> I farmed out **for** a small  fortune to build the  website of my business
>   through freelance web designers.

or only I can say the following sentence

> I farmed out the website of my business through freelance web
>   designers and it cost a small  fortune to me.

EDITED   : small  of fortune

Comment: It is the work that is farmed out, not the cost. The second is OK, except that "a small of fortune" is not English: you mean "a small fortune"; and I think you mean "**to** freelance web designers": if you say "through", that means they are intermediaries and that you farmed it out to somebody else.

Comment: What you farmed out was *the work* involved in building the website. *A small fortune* is what you spent.

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks. I meant actually " a small amount of fortune"

Comment: @ColinFine I have edited the question please check it out.

Comment: @Mrt: "A small amount of fortune" doesn't work either. "Fortune" without an article means "luck", not "wealth". "A fortune" means a large amount of wealth (in this sort of metaphorical use, always money). "A small fortune" is the idiom.

Comment: "A small amount of fortune", while not technically incorrect, is not at all idiomatic.  It's "a small fortune", or "a big chunk of money", or some such.

Comment: @Mrt. No, though it's comprehensible. "farm out" requires a NP (noun phrase), not an infinitive clause; and putting the adjunct "for a small fortune" between the verb and its object is very odd syntax, though not ungrammatical. But please don't edit the substance of your question after people have already commented on it makes the whole thing confusing to people who come along afterwards: at least, if you're going to do that, put a comment **in the question** explaining the edit you've made.

Comment: @ColinFine This thread caused me to ask this question. how about it ? https://kdp.amazon.com/community/thread.jspa?messageID=556835

Comment: @Mrt: "I've farmed out for hundreds of dollars a conversion to KF8 " is grammatical (the object is the NP '"a conversion to KF8") but awkward, because the "for hundreds of dollars" is interposed between the verb and its object.

Comment: *Farm out* normally means to subcontract.  If you are a web developer, and you bid on a contract, and get the contract, but you end up in a time crunch trying to make several tight deadlines, you might pay a subcontractor to carry out certain parts of the job for you.  A *small fortune* means *more money than I really should have spent*, since "fortune" = a lot of money.

Comment: You could "pay out" or idiomatically "shell out" a small fortune to freelancers, if that was your intention.